# Polymer function within object

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope, polymer

I'm having an issue with trying to get a function to work within an array object in Polymer.

The array contains 2 objects with properties such as title, font size and line height. These objects are then put into the DOM and the size and line height values are controlled by range sliders.

My problem is that I can't get the styling functions to work. I think that it is a scoping issue, but I can't figure it out. I know that the functions themselves work as I had them working when I just had the values set as properties, but now that I've created an array I am just getting nowhere.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyhz9pq5/3/)

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}">
    <div class="titleInputContain">
      <input value="{{item.title::input}}">
      <paper-slider min="10" max="200" value="{{item.fontSize}}" editable></paper-slider>
      <paper-slider min="0" max="200" value="{{item.lineHeight}}" editable></paper-slider>
    </div>
  </template>
    <div class="titleBlock">
      <div class="titleText">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}">
          <p class="titleHeader" style$="{{item.styling}}">{{item.title}}</p>
        </template>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'l3-cover',
        ready: function() {
          this.titles = [
            {
              title: 'THIS IS A',
              fontSize: '98',
              lineHeight: '70',
              fontSizeComputed: {
                type: String,
                computed: 'generateStyle("font-size", fontSize, "px")'
              },
              lineHeightComputed: {
                computed: 'generateStyle("line-height", lineHeight, "%")'
              },
              styling: {
                type: String,
                computed: 'this.combineStyles(fontSizeComputed, lineHeightComputed)'
              }
            },
            {
              title: 'STANDARD COVER',
              fontSize: '98',
              lineHeight: '70',
              fontSizeComputed: {
                computed: 'generateStyle("font-size", fontSize, "px")'
              },
              lineHeightComputed: {
                computed: 'generateStyle("line-height", lineHeight, "%")'
              },
              styling: {
                computed: 'combineStyles(fontSizeComputed, lineHeightComputed)'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        generateStyle: function(type, size, value) {
          return type + ':' + size + value + ';';
        },
        combineStyles: function(size, lineheight) {
          return size + lineheight;
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found an answer to this.

Basically, you can have the function as the data bind in the DOM.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyhz9pq5/4/)

```
     <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}">
       <p class="titleHeader" style$="{{generateStyle('font-size', item.fontSize, 'px', 'line-height', item.lineHeight, '%')}}">{{item.title}}</p>
     </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'l3-cover',
        ready: function() {
          this.titles = [
            {
              title: 'THIS IS A',
              fontSize: '98',
              lineHeight: '80'
            },
            {
              title: 'STANDARD COVER',
              fontSize: '50',
              lineHeight: '100'
            }
          ];
        },
        generateStyle: function(type1, size1, value1, type2, size2, value2) {
          return type1 + ':' + size1 + value1 + ';' + type2 + ':' + size2 + value2 + ';';
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
```